# Notification not Viewed in some Infinix Devices

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I just want to show a notification on Android Device.

I'm using NotificationSingelton

```
public class NotificationSingelton {

    public static NotificationSingelton notificationSingelton;
    public static Context context;
    Intent main;

    public static NotificationSingelton getInstance(Context mContext) {
        context = mContext;
        if (notificationSingelton == null) {
            notificationSingelton = new NotificationSingelton();
            return notificationSingelton;
        }
        return notificationSingelton;
    }

    public void sendMeNotification(String message) {

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = null;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("Veezlo","Veezlo", importance);
            channel.setDescription("It's a personal channel");
            channel.enableVibration(false);
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channel.getId());
        } else {
            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"Veezlo");
        }
        Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        notification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentTitle("Adrivee")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(sound)
                .setLights(Color.RED, 200, 200);

        manager.notify(0, notification.build());
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NotificationSingelton.getInstance(this).sendMeNotification("Message Text");
    }
}
```

The Notification working successfully in the Emulator and my physical device "honor 6X".
But when I published the application to the Google play, I found that the notification not working notices on many Infinix devices.

Comment: The way you have the getInstance method always updates the context object, and should only update it if the instance is null. Also, in order to have a complete Singleton implementation, you should include a Private constructor, to ensure the getInstance method its the only way to create an object and always get the unique instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i just changed a few things on the code you posted on the implementation of the Singleton Pattern.

```
    public class NotificationSingelton {
    private static NotificationSingelton notificationSingelton;
    private static Context context;
    
    private NotificationSingelton(Context mContext) {
        context = mContext;
    }

    public static NotificationSingelton getInstance(Context mContext) {
        if (notificationSingelton == null) {
            notificationSingelton = new NotificationSingelton(mContext);
        }
        
        return notificationSingelton;
    }

    public void sendMeNotification(String message) {
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = null;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("Veezlo", "Veezlo", importance);
            channel.setDescription("It's a personal channel");
            channel.enableVibration(false);
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channel.getId());
        }
        else {
            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"Veezlo");
        }
        
        Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        notification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setContentTitle("Adrivee")
        .setContentText(message)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(sound)
        .setLights(Color.RED, 200, 200);

        manager.notify(0, notification.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Infinix devices are very problematic with notifications. You have to enable notification from Notification Management. Go to Phone Master -> Toolbox -> Notification Management (Allow your app to show notification). As far as I understand, you would not be able to do it programmatically instead you can navigate the user to the specified intent.